# Using Sonar's web service java client to persist properties

Tags: java, api, plugins, sonarqube

How can I persist a Sonar Property [using Sonar's web service java client](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+the+Web+Service+Java+client)?

[EDIT:  I realize now that the Web Service Client is not applicable for developing a plugin; rather other classes should be used from Sonar's API.  See the answer I accepted.]
I'm planing to make a plugin for Sonar.  In the meantime, I am familiarizing myself with Sonar's API, and in particular Sonar's web service java client.  I am trying to figure out how to persist a Sonar Property.  I wrote the following code:

```
    package testers;

    import org.sonar.wsclient.Sonar;
    import org.sonar.wsclient.services.Property;
    import org.sonar.wsclient.services.PropertyCreateQuery;
    import org.sonar.wsclient.services.PropertyQuery;

    public class PropertyPersister {

        public static Sonar localSonar;
        public static Property sonarStartTime;
        public static PropertyQuery findStartTime;
        public static Property testProperty;
        public static PropertyQuery findTestProperty;
        public static String testKey = "testKey";
        public static String testValue = "testValue";


        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //localSonar = Sonar.create("http://localhost:9000");//pointed to my instance of Sonar

            //EDIT: using this line instead, but it still gives the same stack trace.
                    localSonar = Sonar.create("http://localhost:9000", "admin", "admin");//pointed to my instance of Sonar

            findStartTime = PropertyQuery.createForKey("sonar.core.startTime");//creating query for a key I know exists
            sonarStartTime = localSonar.find(findStartTime);//retrieve property object from my Sonar's database
            System.out.println(sonarStartTime);//print out this object

            PropertyCreateQuery testCreateQuery = new PropertyCreateQuery(testKey, testValue);//Query to create test property


            localSonar.create(testCreateQuery);//With this line, I'm trying to persist my test property

            findTestProperty = PropertyQuery.createForKey(testKey);//creating query for retrieving test property
            testProperty = localSonar.find(findTestProperty);//line 36: retrieve property object from my Sonar's database
            System.out.println(testProperty);//print test property
        }
    }
```

This code prints out the already existing sonarStartTime property:

```
[sonar.core.startTime:2013-03-14T08:05:42-0700]
```

It is then followed by a null pointer exception thrown by the second-to-last line.  The exception message included:

```
 org.sonar.wsclient.unmarshallers.UnmarshalException: Can not parse the response of query /api/properties/testKey?: {"err_code":404,"err_msg":"Property not found: testKey"}
```

Using MySQL workbench, I confirmed that indeed, my test property was never persisted.  Obviously, I am going about this the wrong way.  So, to reiterate my question, how can I persist a property in Sonar [using Sonar's web service java client](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+the+Web+Service+Java+client)?

[EDIT]  Here is the full console output with stack trace:

```
[sonar.core.startTime:2013-03-14T08:05:42-0700]
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.wsclient.unmarshallers.UnmarshalException: Can not parse the response of query /api/properties/testKey?: {"err_code":404,"err_msg":"Property not found: testKey"}

    at org.sonar.wsclient.Sonar.find(Sonar.java:56)
    at testers.PropertyPersister.main(PropertyPersister.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at org.sonar.wsclient.JdkUtils.getArraySize(JdkUtils.java:87)
    at org.sonar.wsclient.unmarshallers.AbstractUnmarshaller.toModel(AbstractUnmarshaller.java:34)
    at org.sonar.wsclient.Sonar.find(Sonar.java:54)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think that I really AM doing this the right way, but somewhere there is some sort of obscure setting that will not let me persist anything.  I have not been able to find what this setting might be... if anyone could point me the right way I would be grateful.

Comment: I realize now that the Web Service Client is not applicable for developing a plugin but rather for a separate application, so other classes should be used from Sonar's API. See the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonar briefly explains how to re-use existing components of their API [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Coding+a+Plugin).

You could simply declare a DatabaseSession in the constructor of your class where you are attempting to persist a property.  For example:

```
import org.sonar.api.database.DatabaseSession;
import org.sonar.api.database.configuration.Property;
import org.sonar.api.resources.Project;
import org.sonar.api.resources.Resource;

public class PropertyPersister{

    private DatabaseSession session;
    private Project project;
    private Property newProperty;

    public PropertyPersister (DatabaseSession session, Project project){
    this.session = session;
    this.project = project; 
    }

    private void persistProperty (Resource resource) {
        int resourceId= resource.getId();       
        newProperty = new Property("sonar.myFabulousProperty", "someValue", resourceId);
        session.save(newProperty);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Sonar's Web Service Client API is not really applicable for the actual plugin.  This is what I really wanted after all.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to push data to Sonar, this requires to have admin credentials.

So you should create the "org.sonar.wsclient.Sonar" instance like this:

```
localSonar = Sonar.create("http://localhost:9000", "admin", "admin");
```

Comment: Hey Fabrice, thanks for the response!  However, I tried adding the admin credentials as you suggested, but it still didn't work and gives me the same stack trace, so I think there is also something else I'm not understanding correctly about the api.  Is passing a CreatePropertyQuery into localSonar.create() the correct way to persist a property?

Comment: Correction to above comment.  I said "CreatePropertyQuery" in above comment when I meant "PropertyCreateQuery".  So my question is, if I want to persist a property using the wsclient, is passing a PropertyCreateQuery to the method, localSonar.create() the correct way to do this?  If so, what am I doing wrong that is causing my test property to not persist?